# PhpStorm cannot connect to PDO / MySQL - everything else can. Error "could not find driver"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpstorm

This morning, everything was beautiful - then I reinstalled PhpStorm :-(

My mistake was probably a full uninstall, including config & settings, then a reisntall.

Everything else that I can think of works and that is the only thing that I have changed.

- Apache is running nicely
- I can invoke mysql.exe & access my databases
- as can HeidiSQL
- and Visual Studio Code can execute queries
- `phpinfo()` shows `PDO drivers   no value`, but I believe that to be standard now; also the others are OK
- `php -m` shows PDO

If you need code, the exception is thrown at

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . $databaseName, DATABSE_USER_NAME, DATABSE_PASSWORD);
```

but I have not changed that code in years.

All that I have changed today is the uninstall & reinstall of PhpStorm - and that code was executing successfully this morning.

How can I get this working again?

Comment: Show screenshots with the error and how you run the code (what do you click/press to have it running). Right now it looks like you are using the wrong PHP Interpreter (different to what your Apache PHP uses) when executing your code from PhpStorm.

Comment: Can we re-open this please? I looked at the one recommended as dupe, found not enough info, googled, added it to that question - use menu "View | Tool Windows | Database", as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html BUT, when I do that I *can* access my database - but not form my PHP code (which has not changed; I just need to configure PPHstorm correctly). Thanks

Comment: Also, I am using the correct PHP interpreter in PHP storm (it was auto-detected & I only have one. As to having it running, I load a PHP page with form in the browser & click the "submit" button. The PHP interpreter is fine, it is something to do with configuring. Thanks for your help

Comment: So what is has to do with PhpStorm then .. if all works in web browser and it's the only PHP installation that you have. I'm sorry, but with such limited info _I personally_ cannot suggest anything more concrete except "go and check your PHP -- see if it uses different configs or whatnot".

Comment: 1) Close PhpStorm 2) Open your web page in web browser -- the page that works with database. Does it work? If not -- check your PHP config. If yes -- how does it differ to when PhpStorm is used?

Comment: Thanks, very much for your help (+1). Oddly, it has stopped working in the browser too, so reinstalling PHPstorm was just a distraction. It's a form action which should load a page that 100% does exist & nothing in that code changed for months, maybe years. I am stumped, but have a better idea of where to investigate now.

Comment: In fact, that was working yesterday, when I first posted, as the PDO connect is in the form action, which the browser now cannot find (!?). Even adding an echo as the first line was not seen, so the browser really thinks that it cannot find it. Strange days, indeed